# Assigning 16-bit samples to a WriteableRaster

Tags: java, clojure, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

How do I create a 16-bit-per-channel image in Clojure?

I am working with the ImageIO class for reading and writing image files, and it seems to read image files just fine.  It even appears to put the 16-bit data into the correct color bands.

But, my application requires a transformation, specifically Gimp's "overlay" transformation, that I must apply by looking at the image data for two separate images.  So, from each image, I grab the raw data from corresponding bands, run the transformation, and then write the result to a new image.

But, I cannot find a way to make the new image accept 16-bit values.  I have to scale the result down from 16-bits per channel to 8-bits per channel, which I don't want to do.

I am creating my image like so:

```
(BufferedImage. 800 600 BufferedImage/TYPE_INT_RGB)
```

Which should be equivalent to

```
BufferedImage anon = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Now, is there a way to create a new BufferedImage which accepts 16-bits per channel?  Or do I have to switch to a different library?

If I switch, my requirements are...

a) Color Space awareness
b) 16 bits per channel

Until then, I will do my best with 8-bits.

**Update 2011/08/10**:
While it could be up to two weeks before I can try this, it would appear that Java's Advanced Imaging API (JAI) does what I need.  It supports color spaces and supports up to 32 bits per channel/band.

Comment: I'm writing an image library for clojure called [rinzelight](http://github.com/Serabe/rinzelight). It uses TYPE_INT_ARGB for images but you can change it before saving using the `assure-rgb` function. I have never been able to use 16 bits per channel, I usually convert from and to 8 bit. If you have any request for rinzelight, use the issues there and I'll try to help you if I can.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong) this:

```
(BufferedImage. 800 600 BufferedImage/TYPE_INT_RGB)
```

is **not** equivalent to (*):

```
BufferedImage anon = BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

but rather to:

```
BufferedImage anon = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

If you want (*) then do:

```
(. BufferedImage 800 600 BufferedImage/TYPE_INT_RGB)
```

Maybe a typo in your post... or maybe not?
*(Yes, this should be a comment but I can't do it yet)*

Comment: Typo, lack of familiarity with Java.  "new BufferedImage" would be the Java equivalent that I desire, though I put that in just to illustrate what I was generally getting at to people as unfamiliar with Clojure as I am with Java.